# What would lead to a "Cancelling deletion of pod" message?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I see these messages in my GKE logs several times a day...

> Cancelling deletion of Pod <pod-namespace>/<pod name>

It looks like they are happening due to the `taint-controller` with a reason of `TaintManagerEviction`

I'm hoping for help with:

1. Why is this happening?
2. When the pod is first flagged to be deleted, what happens to the pod? Is a `SIGTERM` sent to it or something?

I've seen instances where the pod *has* been deleted/moved to a different node anyway despite the cancellation, or even immediately rescheduled to the same node...

Any suggestions on what it is doing and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you found an answer already since this is an old question. For anyone who has yet to find an answer, [this post](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5567801) may provide some insight. It basically says that you will experience this if your pod has `tolerationSeconds` set in its `tolerations` section. Removing this field will "solve" this issue.

**Explanation**

It is observed that while using tolerationSeconds parameter, it causes synchronized recreation of pods.
It is an optional field that dictates how long the pod will stay bound to the node after the taint is added. For instance, if it is set to 6000seconds (1h40m) then the pod will stay bound to the node for 6000 seconds, and then be evicted.

Comment: I'd always wandered what that `tolerationSeconds` was for... Does this mean that the nodes are randomly getting and then having their taints removed?